# How to only copy array elements to spreadsheet if conditions met

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a script to copy CSV data to a Google Sheet. The CSV is converted to a 2D Array `trades`, and a `forEach` loops through each element/row of `trades`, named `trade`. I'm trying to make it check if the data is in the spreadsheet, and if it is, skip copying that entry. The way I'm identifying each trade is by the date (column A [or 0]) and trade index (column W [or 22]). If the trade has the same date and trade index, it should not be copied. As I have it now, it runs correctly against test data in the sheet (e.g. if I change the first entry, ticker UUU, to have the same date & index as one of the entries in the array), but when run a second time, it does not recognize the previously added entries (with identical dates & indexes) and it continues to copy duplicates.

How can I improve this code to work as intended and not copy duplicates, contrary to what is intended? How can I test rows in sheet and only copy entries from the array that are not already present in the sheet?

Below is the relevant code I'm working with.

[This is a copy of the google sheet I'm playing with.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FtnGBsoXtTrCuuY-Lh3YMaDS5uKH96j7C7MysPBubck/edit?usp=sharing) The first entry is the test data mentioned above. The three subsequent entries are the result of the test array being copied using the below code (and other less relevant code).

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###');
let log = ss.getSheetByName("Log");

trades.forEach(function(trade) {

      //Housekeeping code deleted

      //Relevant code:

      let data = log.getDataRange().getValues();
      for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++){

        let dateRange = log.getRange("A:A");
        let dateValues = dateRange.getValues();
        let numberRange = log.getRange("W:W");
        let numberValues = numberRange.getValues();
        let date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateValues[i]), "PST", "yyyy-MM-dd");
        let tradeNum = numberValues[i];

        if(date == trade[0] && tradeNum == trade[22]) {
          break;
        };

        let insertRow = log.getDataRange().getValues().length + 1; //Non-index (saved already above)
        let importedData = log.getRange(insertRow,1,1,trade.length).setValues(new Array(trade));
        return insertRow, importedData;
      };

      return insertRow;

    });
```

### UPDATE

Thanks to [Abdellah's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9388511/abdellah-hariti) well written answer and [Neven's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9418616/neven-subotic) helpful advice, the following solution is working perfectly:

```
    //Get existing trades
    let loggedTrades = log.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1); // Removed header

    //Method to join date & trade index to create unique trade ID
    const createId = (trade) =>
      Utilities.formatDate(new Date(trade[0]), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd") + trade[22];

    //Map new array of existing trades' unique trade IDs
    let loggedTradesId = loggedTrades.map(trade => 
      createId(trade));
    
    //Filter to create new array of elements in trades array that are not already in sheet (in loggedTrades)
    let newTrades = trades.filter(
      (trade) => !loggedTradesId.includes(createId(trade))
    );

    //Import newTrades to sheet 
    if(newTrades.length > 0) {
      
      let insertRow = log.getLastRow() + 1; //Non-index (saved already above)
      let importedData = 
      log.getRange(
        insertRow,
        1,
        newTrades.length,
        newTrades[0].length
      ).setValues(newTrades);
    };
```

Comment: When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that there are several functions in your Google Apps Script project. So I cannot understand about your script in your question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi, thanks, happy to clarify. I will update the main question, too. How can I improve this code to work as intended? What is written incorrectly that causes it to copy duplicates, contrary to what is intended? Is there a better way to test rows in sheet and only copy entries from the array that are not already present in the sheet?

Comment: You have several undefined variables

Comment: This is only the relevant code. I assume it would be too large to include. I'll add the variables to help clarify

Comment: relevant code must still be [mcve].  Sorry if we're forcing you to have to think a little.

Comment: The attitude is unnecessary. This is hardly a ploy to avoid thought. As a learning coder, I invested considerable thought before posing the question. I will do my best to make this reproducible, without burdening the question with irrelevant details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that:

1. gathers the existing rows focusing on the relevant fields in a `Set` for faster lookup.
2. filter the csv rows based on the same logic.
3. appends everything to the log sheet in one go.

```js
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###");
let log = ss.getSheetByName("Log");

const stringyfyTrade = (trade) =>
  trade[22] + Utilities.formatDate(trade[0], "PST", "yyyy-MM-dd");

// create a set of existing trades (from the trades date+index) for faster lookup
let alreadyLoggedTrades = new Set(
  log
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues()
    // get rid of header row
    .slice(1)
    .map(stringyfyTrade)
);

// gather non logged trades in one go
let nonLoggedTrades = trades.filter(
  (trade) => !alreadyLoggedTrades.has(stringyfyTrade(trade))
);

// append them if there are any
if (nonLoggedTrades.length > 0) {
  s.getRange(
    s.getLastRow() + 1,
    1,
    nonLoggedTrades.length,
    nonLoggedTrades[0].length
  ).setValues(nonLoggedTrades);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- The variable declaration for `data` within a for-loop is a bad/slow way to handle this. Instead, call it once outside the for-loop and then you can always append new rows, if they do not exist.
- In order to check if a record already exists, you could just create one array which holds all the existing ids and test against it. Then add any new ids to it.
- I recommend to work with Objects, i.e. where the column header is the key, and the cell value is the value, e.g. `{"Gross PnL": 1.40}`.
- You are `break`ing out of the for-loop instead of `continue`ing to the next item in the loop. [Break vs Continue](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp).